# How to compare variable strings within a line

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am struggling with grep, awk and sed with this issue. I have an XML with lines like these:

```
<field type="float8" name="something" database_fieldname="SHORT" allowsnull="false"/>
<field type="float8" name="LONG" database_fieldname="LONG" allowsnull="false"/>
```

I want to isolate those lines where the values for *name=* and *database_fieldname=* are identical, and, if that is the case, remove the entire field *database_fieldname=*. Expected output:

```
<field type="float8" name="something" database_fieldname="SHORT" allowsnull="false"/>
<field type="float8" name="LONG" allowsnull="false"/>
```

Comment: XML files should be used/search/build with XML tools (xmllint/xmlstarlet/xsltproc). You should move this question to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` approximation to a solution:

```
awk '
        {match ($0, / name="[^"]*"/)
         R1 = RSTART
         L1 = RLENGTH
         match ($0, / database_fieldname="[^"]*"/)
         R2 = RSTART
         L2 = RLENGTH
         if (substr ($0, R1+7, L1-8) == substr ($0, R2+21, L2-22)) sub (substr ($0, R2, L2), "")
        }
1
' file
<field type="float8" name="something" database_fieldname="SHORT" allowsnull="false"/>
<field type="float8" name="LONG" allowsnull="false"/>
```

It matches both target fields, extracts their values for comparison, and, if equal, substitutes the second entirely with the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a backreference in your search pattern:

```
sed -e 's/name="\(.*\)" database_fieldname="\1"/name="\1"/' <input>
```